# HttpWebRequest.Proxy being null vs GetSystemWebProxy

Tags: httpwebrequest

I wish to know what is the correct approach to set the WebProxy to be used by HttpWebRequest.Proxy property.

Following are the options available:

1. Set the Proxy property to Null or Don’t set the property at all. This would use the IE’s default proxy configuration or default proxy in the web config.
2. Set the Proxy property to System.Net.GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy to bypass any proxy.
3. Set the Proxy property to WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy. Set the proxy from IE proxy settings for the current user.

Between option 1 and 3 what is the correct approacy. 
For best performance what should be the default Proxy. Should it be set to null or don't set any value at all or should it be GetSystemWebProxy.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use option 1, if you do not set the value - the code will execute using the system settings. Setting a value of null is just useless code cluttering up your other code in my opinion. I don't know that there is a 'correct approach' - but if so I'd assume this to be it.

Answer (score 0):

I use Proxy = Nothing as had other users experience issues in the past when they are using VPN / proxies in IE that require authentication & when IE is not open the program will not allow a connection. You could always give the user the option if you are distributing your software.